# crop an image of icons

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, react-native

I just want to know how to display a part of an image in react-native

```
class InstaClone extends Component {
render() {
    return(
        <View style={{ flex:1, width:100 + "%", height:100 + "%" }}>
            <View style={styles.TopNavStyle}>
                <Text style={styles.TopNavTextStyle}>
                    Instagram
                </Text>
            </View>

            <View style = {styles.userBar}>
            <View style = {{ flexDirection:"row" , alignItems:"center" }}>
                <Image style = {styles.userPic}
                    source = {require('../assets/images/photoUser.jpg')}/>
                <Text style = {{marginLeft : 10}}>
                    Mohcouch
                </Text>
            </View>

            <View>
            <View style={styles.imageContainer}>
                <ImageBackground
                source={require('../assets/images/icons.jpg')}
                style={styles.image}
                ></ImageBackground>
            </View>
            </View>
            </View>
            <Image 
            style={{ width:"100%", height:400 }} 
            source={require('../assets/images/baby.jpg')} 
            />
        </View>

    )
}
```

}

```
} , image: {
    height: 500,
    width: 500,
    resizeMode:"cover",
    translateX:-80,
    translateY: -135,

  },
  imageContainer: {
    height: 40,
    backgroundColor:'transparent',
    width: 40,
  },
```

})

export default InstaClone

Result :

https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.15752-0/p280x280/58461695_2231014486986604_1022634010985103360_n.png?_nc_cat=102&_nc_ad=z-m&_nc_cid=0&_nc_zor=9&_nc_ht=scontent.xx&oh=cb81348aae1c524ba9e93d1e02afb120&oe=5D44DF9C

the image of icons :
https://scontent.xx.fbcdn.net/v/t1.15752-0/p280x280/51865955_790216374668323_1242853141917990912_n.jpg?_nc_cat=102&_nc_ad=z-m&_nc_cid=0&_nc_zor=9&_nc_ht=scontent.xx&oh=1c6d18d17e24ec68771be2590fc934c4&oe=5D2CC871

Comment: Your best shot will be to use a photo editor tool and crop image into separate files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

React Native doesn's support a property `background-position`. It is better to separate the icons in different image files.

But there is a tricky workaround that you can use with your sprite image:

First, you need to round the image pixels in layout size (dp):

```
const width = PixelRatio.roundToNearestPixel(280);
const height = PixelRatio.roundToNearestPixel(280);
```

**Note**: 280 is the size of the image from your post

Then, we need to calculate the same proportion for the size of the icon:

```
const iconWidth = PixelRatio.roundToNearestPixel(30);
const iconHeight = PixelRatio.roundToNearestPixel(30);
```

**Note**: 30 is a random size for our icon, it can be any size.

Now, for the loading of the image, we will use the `ImageBackground` component from [react-native](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/imagebackground). For `imageStyle` we will pass the positioning properties of the image:

```
imageStyle={{
    resizeMode: 'cover',
    width: width, height: height,
    top: -15,
    left: -15
}}
```

Your component should look like this:

```
<ImageBackground
    source={{ uri: image_url }}
    style={{ width: iconWidth, height: iconHeight, overflow: 'hidden' }}
    imageStyle={{
        resizeMode: 'cover',
        width: width, height: height,
        top: -15,
        left: -15
    }}
/>
```

Here is a working [demo](https://snack.expo.io/rJF6_525N).