# Image Sheet in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-image, react-image-crop

Any idea how to use image sheets in react native? For instance, if I have an image sheet like this, is there a way that I can define the frame dimensions and reuse one single image to display multiple icons?

[image]

similar question: [How can I use my spritesheet of icons in react native?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66958527/how-can-i-use-my-spritesheet-of-icons-in-react-native)

Found an approach of using ImageBackground: [crop an image of icons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55808942/crop-an-image-of-icons)

Exploring other options.

Answer (score 0):

As a solution:

You can convert your image (jpg/png/jpeg) to an SVG file then use this SVG to create a react component to use on your React Native application.

##### Explanation

**First step**
convert your image to SVG using converter tools. you can also use online websites like [pngtosvg](https://www.pngtosvg.com/)

**Second step**
convert the SVG to the valid component using online tools like [react-svgr](https://react-svgr.com/playground/?native=true)  or [svg2jsx](https://svg2jsx.com/)

**Third step**
Assume you get the below component:

```
import * as React from "react"
import Svg, { Path } from "react-native-svg"

function SvgComponent(props) {
  return (
    <Svg width={48} height={1} xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" {...props}>
      <Path d="M0 0h48v1H0z" fill="#063855" fillRule="evenodd" />
    </Svg>
  )
}

export default SvgComponent
```

Now, import it as a regular component in your application.